# Remove lines IF AND THEN ELSEIF

Tags: vba, excel

Everyone!

I have a heavy file with different values in A and D columns.
Now I want this script to complete the following operation:

1. If value in column A is "Option One" and "K" in column D, then remove this entire line.
2. Additionally Remove entire raw if value in column A is "Option Two" and "M" in column D

The following code performs this operation for 70% and I can't find the issue.
It always leaves behind some rows and to completely remove unwanted entries, I have to run this code twice.

Will appreciate your help! Thank You!

```
Sub RemoveSomeLines()

Dim RemoveRow As Long

RemoveRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For y = 1 To RemoveRow
If Cells(y, "A").Value = "Option One" And _
   Cells(y, "D").Value = "K" Then
   Cells(y, "A").EntireRow.Delete

ElseIf Cells(y, "A").Value = "Option Two" And _
   Cells(y, "D").Value = "M" Then
   Cells(y, "A").EntireRow.Delete

End If
Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `rows(y).EntireRow.Delete` Also try two `if` statements instead of `elseif`.

Comment: same thing.. some rows are still behind. 10 sec

Comment: The problem is that the for loop when it finds what it needs to delete it deletes the line then moves the next line up into its place, but the next time the loop fires it moves to the next row effectively skipping the row. Try putting `y=y-1` after the delet row line.

Comment: Oh yea I always forget too, what @ScottCraner said.

Comment: thank you very much guys! this solution worked! we have 2 good solutions for this case!

Answer (score 4):

Try going backwards:

```
For y = RemoveRow To 1 Step -1
```

It is probably skipping rows because you are removing a row, moving the next row up, and then skipping the row that was moved up on the next loop because y increments by 1.

It looks like this:

Remove row 20.
Entire sheet shifts upward.
Row 21 is now row 20.
y increments on the next loop to become 21.
The new row 20 was actually skipped entirely.

Alternatively, I think it would work if you decremented y by 1 when you removed a row, but it's less code changes just to work backward instead of forward.

Comment: Good catch I forget sometimes that I can step backwards.